# Error in console: Functions are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I keep on getting this error when trying to update a product in my project:

react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import store from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

ProductList:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, useParams, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  createProduct,
  deleteProduct,
  listProducts,
} from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import {
  PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET,
  PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET,
} from '../constants/productConstants';

export default function ProductListScreen(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { pageNumber = 1 } = useParams();
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const sellerMode = pathname.indexOf('/seller') >= 0;
  const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
  const { loading, error, products, page, pages } = productList;

  const productCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productCreate);
  const {
    loading: loadingCreate,
    error: errorCreate,
    success: successCreate,
    product: createdProduct,
  } = productCreate;

  const productDelete = useSelector((state) => state.productDelete);
  const {
    loading: loadingDelete,
    error: errorDelete,
    success: successDelete,
  } = productDelete;
  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (successCreate) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_CREATE_RESET });
      navigate(`/product/${createdProduct._id}/edit`);
    }
    if (successDelete) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DELETE_RESET });
    }
    dispatch(
      listProducts({ seller: sellerMode ? userInfo._id : '', pageNumber })
    );
  }, [
    createdProduct,
    dispatch,
    navigate,
    sellerMode,
    successCreate,
    successDelete,
    userInfo._id,
    pageNumber,
  ]);

  const deleteHandler = (product) => {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure to delete?')) {
      dispatch(deleteProduct(product._id));
    }
  };
  const createHandler = () => {
    dispatch(createProduct());
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="row">
        <h1>Products</h1>
        <button type="button" className="primary" onClick={createHandler}>
          Create Product
        </button>
      </div>

      {loadingDelete && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorDelete && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorDelete}</MessageBox>}

      {loadingCreate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
      {errorCreate && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorCreate}</MessageBox>}
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
      ) : (
        <>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
                <th>CATEGORY</th>
                <th>BRAND</th>
                <th>ACTIONS</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {products.map((product) => (
                <tr key={product._id}>
                  <td>{product._id}</td>
                  <td>{product.name}</td>
                  <td>{product.price}</td>
                  <td>{product.category}</td>
                  <td>{product.brand}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="small"
                      onClick={() => navigate(`/product/${product._id}/edit`)}
                    >
                      Edit
                    </button>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="small"
                      onClick={() => deleteHandler(product)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div className="row center pagination">
            {[...Array(pages).keys()].map((x) => (
              <Link
                className={x + 1 === page ? 'active' : ''}
                key={x + 1}
                to={`/productlist/pageNumber/${x + 1}`}
              >
                {x + 1}
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Product Edit Page:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { detailsProduct, updateProduct } from '../actions/productActions';
import LoadingBox from '../components/LoadingBox';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';
import { PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET } from '../constants/productConstants';

export default function ProductEditScreen(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const { id: productId } = params;
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
  const [countInStock, setCountInStock] = useState('');
  const [brand, setBrand] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  const productUpdate = useSelector((state) => state.productUpdate);
  const {
    loading: loadingUpdate,
    error: errorUpdate,
    success: successUpdate,
  } = productUpdate;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (successUpdate) {
      navigate('/productlist');
    }
    if (!product || product._id !== productId || successUpdate) {
      dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_UPDATE_RESET });
      dispatch(detailsProduct(productId));
    } else {
      setName(product.name);
      setPrice(product.price);
      setImage(product.image);
      setCategory(product.category);
      setCountInStock(product.countInStock);
      setBrand(product.brand);
      setDescription(product.description);
    }
  }, [product, dispatch, productId, successUpdate, navigate]);
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // TODO: dispatch update product
    dispatch(
      updateProduct({
        _id: productId,
        name,
        price,
        image,
        category,
        brand,
        countInStock,
        description,
      })
    );
  };
  const [loadingUpload, setLoadingUpload] = useState(false);
  const [errorUpload, setErrorUpload] = useState('');

  const userSignin = useSelector((state) => state.userSignin);
  const { userInfo } = userSignin;
  const uploadFileHandler = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('image', file);
    setLoadingUpload(true);
    try {
      const { data } = await Axios.post('/api/uploads', bodyFormData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
        },
      });
      setImage(data);
      setLoadingUpload(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setErrorUpload(error.message);
      setLoadingUpload(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div>
          <h1>Edit Product {productId}</h1>
        </div>
        {loadingUpdate && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
        {errorUpdate && <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorUpdate}</MessageBox>}
        {loading ? (
          <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
        ) : error ? (
          <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        ) : (
          <>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
              <input
                id="name"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter name"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
              <input
                id="price"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter price"
                value={price}
                onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="image">Image</label>
              <input
                id="image"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter image"
                value={image}
                onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="imageFile">Image File</label>
              <input
                type="file"
                id="imageFile"
                label="Choose Image"
                onChange={uploadFileHandler}
              ></input>
              {loadingUpload && <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>}
              {errorUpload && (
                <MessageBox variant="danger">{errorUpload}</MessageBox>
              )}
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="category">Category</label>
              <input
                id="category"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter category"
                value={category}
                onChange={(e) => setCategory(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="brand">Brand</label>
              <input
                id="brand"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter brand"
                value={brand}
                onChange={(e) => setBrand(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="countInStock">Count In Stock</label>
              <input
                id="countInStock"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter countInStock"
                value={countInStock}
                onChange={(e) => setCountInStock(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
              <textarea
                id="description"
                rows="3"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter description"
                value={description}
                onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label></label>
              <button className="primary" type="submit">
                Update
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

what could be the problem?

The code should redirect me to a new page in which i can create a new product and add it to my database